# Expandable overlay widget

Tags: android, ios, flutter, android-widget, flutter-animation

I would like to create a widget similar to the image below. It should be expandable on drag and should overlay other widgets when it is expanded. Any ideas on that?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Idk your widget structure but you can use simply Stack widget for every items

Comment: Can you show your code? You can implement it using `Stack()` I assume

Comment: Added a gif, does it make sense now?

Comment: We need minimal reproducible code snippet

Comment: What do you mean by reproducible code? I couldn't implement such a widget. I was asking if anyone has any ideas how can I do that. How can it be done with stack?